# Input will not respond to blur if focused while another input is focused

Tags: react-native

Im having a strange issue where manually blurring and input in one spesific case will not work.

If i click the first input, then focus the second input by using the submit key on the keyboard, the onChangeText function on the second input will blur when text length reaches 2.

But if i focus the second input while the fist input is focused by clicking directly on it, the blur method called in the onChangeText will not blur the second input, and the keyboard will remain open.

```
onChangeText(text) {
    if(text.length === 2) this.secondInput.blur();
}

onSubmitFirst() {
    this.firstInput.blur();
    this.secondInput.focus();
}

render() {
    return (
        <TextInput ref={ref => {this.firstInput = ref} onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmitFirst}/>
        <TextInput ref={ref => {this.secondInput = ref} onChangeText={this.onChangeText}/>
    )
}
```

I have also tried with Keyboard.dismiss(); dismissKeyboard(); neither will blur the second input if it was focused while the first input was also focused. I need to be able to blur this input by code to prevent the keyboard from remaining open.

EDIT

It seems .blur() will only work if .focus() has been called manually.

If i add onBlur={() => this.secondInput.focus()} to the first textinput the .blur() method will work even if im jumping to the next input by clicking on it

Comment: Seems to be working fine, I'm clicking the `second TextInput` manually , once the `first one` is `focused initally ` on render, and it blur's when I type `2 letters`. I'm testing on IOS btw.

Comment: Does this also work if u add 
componentDidMount() {
    this.firstInput.focus()
}
?

Comment: Yes, just make sure that your condition is met `text.length === 2`